# EF Core GetAll entries does not include referenced objects for all entries

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I have a problem with EF where when I get all entries which has a list of associated activities.
Then it is only the last Entry which references the particular activity, which has the activity in its list of activities.

E.g.

1. `Entry1` has a list that include `Activity1`
2. `Entry2` has a list that include `Activity1`
3. When I retrieve all of the Entries from the DB using EF. Then it is only `Entry2` which contains `Acivity1`, instead of both of them

I have the following EF configuration

```cs
public class WeeklyReviewBlazorClientDbContext : WeeklyReviewDbContext
{
    public WeeklyReviewBlazorClientDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(WeeklyReviewBlazorClientDbContext).Assembly);
    }
}

// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WeeklyReviewBlazorClientDbContext>(options =>
{
    //options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "WeeklyReview"); 
});
```

The problem is with the following method

```cs
public IEnumerable<EntryModel> GetAll()
{
    return _db.Entry.Include(x => x.Activities).Where(x => x.UserGuid == UserGuid).ToList();
    return _db.Entry.Include(x => x.Activities).Where(x => x.UserGuid == UserGuid).AsNoTracking().ToList(); // Also tried this
}
```

It does not return what I expect.
The following test case shows what I mean.

```cs
public void Test()
{
    var aBreakfast = new ActivityModel("Breakfast");
    var aDinner = new ActivityModel("Dinner");
    _db.Activities.AddRange(aBreakfast, aDinner);
    AddEntry(aBreakfast);
    var entries1 = GetAll();    // Retrives one entry with a Breakfast Activity
    AddEntry(aDinner);          
    var entries2 = GetAll();    // Retrives two entries first with a Breakfast and second with a Dinner Activity
    AddEntry(aBreakfast);
    var entries3 = GetAll();    // Retrives three entries first without the Breakfast, second with Dinner and the last with the Breakfast Activity
                                // This should have returned a Breakfast, Dinner and a Breakfast
}

public void AddEntry(ActivityModel activity)
{
    var entry = new EntryModel(_timeService.Current, new List<ActivityModel>(), UserGuid);
    entry.Activities.Add(activity);
    _db.Entry.Add(entry);
}
```

The two models are:

```cs
public class ActivityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedName { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public CategoryModel Category { get; set; }
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
}

public class EntryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecordedTime{ get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration => EndTime.HasValue ? EndTime.Value - StartTime : TimeSpan.Zero;
    public List<ActivityModel> Activities { get; set; } // Also tried 
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
}
```

I think it has something to do with duplicate keys, as the Breakfast activity is referenced by two entries, and therefore the last entry is the only one which is able to reference it.
Because the first entry which references the Breakfast Activity.

For a better look at the context, you can have a look [here](https://github.com/theodor349/WeeklyReview/blob/feature/refactorClient/WeeklyReviewSource/WeeklyReview/Client/Services/ClientWeeklyReviewService.cs).

Comment: Did you try running with in-memory SQLite driver (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy#sqlite-as-a-database-fake) ? In-Memory is not recommended even by official docs, and I've seen multiple similar situations where it would break navigation properties (more than worthless IMO - creates false fail conditions and fails to catch actual problems in tests)

Comment: I have not, but I'll try today or tomorrow. And thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Maybe you have reference problem. Did you try to create a new instance  of activity model in AddEntry method?

Comment: I've tried testing it with SQLite, but without success. As I'm trying to make it work in a Blazor WASM project. And I've not been able to install SQLite correctly

Comment: You can't add the same `Activity` entity twice. The last `AddEntry(aBreakfast);` "steals:" it from the first `EntryModel`. You have to create two `new Activity("Breakfast")` instances. Just think of how the database should store it. An `ActivityModel` can refer to one `EntryModel` only. BTW, it's confusing that you mix `ActivityModel` and `Activity`.

Comment: It is the Entry which references 1 or more activities. 
So the database would have three tables for entries, activities and one which stores the many to many relationship between them

Comment: The code doesn't make that clear. You offer an `Activity` object to an `AddEntry` method that accepts an `ActivityModel`, which makes it look like a typo.

Comment: Yea that definitely is a mistake

Comment: Gert Arnold is right: adding twice the same instance **aBreakfast** after it has been saved the first time, will not add a new row in ActivityModel table, because **Id** is the same. It's not a problem of SQL or SQLite...

Comment: The `aBreakfast` is supposed to only be added once to the `ActivityModel` table, the problem is that all entries that reference it, is not returned with a reference. It is only the last added entry with a reference that has it.

Answer (score 0):

In your **AddEntry** method, You should **add** the activity to the List of the Activities already present. So your code should be:

```
public void AddEntry(ActivityModel activity)
{
    //I don't think this line of your code works, because there would be a constructor:
    var entry = new EntryModel(_timeService.Current, new List<ActivityModel>(), UserGuid);

    entry.Activities.Add(activity);
    _db.Entry.Add(entry);
}
```

Comment: This is actually done behind the scene as the Add method first creates and adds the activity to Activities, before then creating the Entry

Comment: Yes, but last line of code of your method, create a new List every time, so only the actual object (activity) will be saved.

Comment: Ohh yea that's a good point

Comment: I have update the question to include that change. But it is not the problem as the question is a simplified version of the actual context. 
Because the creation of Entries and Activities is done somewhere else, which works perfectly fine when connecting to an SQL server database.